# Is Oracle alter table drop constraint drop index syntactically valid?

Tags: oracle, syntax, oracle11g, alter-table

I have Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 and a table with unique constraint created by following script:

```
    create table foo (id varchar(26) not null, name varchar(50) not null);
    alter table foo add constraint pk_foo primary key (id);
    /**/
    alter table foo add constraint un_foo unique (name);
```

I need to drop the unique constraint, which is easy:

```
    alter table foo drop constraint un_foo;
```

The trouble is: when the database is backuped in SQL Developer and then restored, then the `un_foo` unique index is created by *explicit* command placed at `/**/` line:

```
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX un_foo ON foo (name);
```

Such an explicitly-created index is not deleted by the alter command above. I realized following command works:

```
    alter table foo drop constraint un_foo drop index;
```

For primary key, similar command `alter table foo drop primary key drop index` is in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#i2103997) or in [Oracle Developer Community discussion](https://community.oracle.com/thread/369159?tstart=0#jive-49506947713850139498868). Also, [this answer at AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1232036500184#followup-426367200346607590) uses this syntax too (for `keep index`). However I don't see any reasoning for such syntax in railroad diagram of `alter table` command.

Question: is the syntax `alter table foo drop constraint un_foo drop index` legal? If so, based on what documentation or flow in railroad diagram? If not, why the command doesn't fail?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to @[Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)'s answer to [my equivalent question posted to AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:9537137900346228604), the syntax is confirmed as working but not present in documentation.
The decision whether it is doc bug or unintended side effect is still unresolved.

I personally decided to rely on the syntax since, among other things, it is advised also in My Oracle Support.

If absolute safety (read: conforming to the documentation) is required, the only possibility is to use statement `alter table foo drop unique (name) drop index;`.

I summarized (not so substantial) circumstances around this issue in [blogpost](http://tomaszalusky.blogspot.cz/2017/11/jak-smazat-na-oraclu-unique-constraint.html) (in Czech).